# Form submission works on windows dev machine but not linux production server

Tags: forms, atk4

So i have a bit of a complex generated form happening which works fine on my windows xampp server but the dropdown field value is not retrieved after submission on my linux production server - any ideas why??

```
    $f=$block->add('Form');

    if($dropdown) {
        $f->addField('Dropdown',$dropdown['value'],$dropdown['label'])
            ->setModel($dropdown['model']);

    }

    // Button
    $b=$f->add('Button')->setLabel($label);

    if($dropdown) {
        $b->js('click', $f->js()->atk4_form('submitForm'));
    }
    else {
        $b->js('click')->univ()
            ->newWindow($this->api->getDestinationURL(
                                './details',
                                array('model'=>$model,'type'=>$type)
                                )
                        )
                        ->execute();    
    }

    $block->add('HR');


if($f->isSubmitted()){
    $f->js()->univ()
            ->newWindow($this->api->getDestinationURL(
                                './details',
                                array(
                                        'model'=>$model,
                                        'type'=>$type,
                                        'field'=>'home_'.$dayShort,
                                        'value'=>$f->get($dropdown['value'])
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                        ->execute();    

    }

}
```

the part that does work in windows but not linux is `'value'=>$f->get($dropdown['value'])` near the end

any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks
Greg

Answer (score 1):

When whatever thing works in Windows and don't work in Linux first thing to check out is upper / lower case letters in classnames and filenames.

In this particular case I guess your mistake is because you have addField('Dropdown'), but should have addField('Drop**D**own') with uppercase D in "down".

Comment: Either that or some problems with SUHOSIN

Comment: Capitalisation of DropDown doesn't seem to change anything - though I thought I'd fixed any of them so thanks for noticing that @DarkSide! @romaninsh what in SUHOSIN would cause it? every other form works fine??

Comment: In Suhosin it can be some problem with to long ID or Name of HTML element.